# Editing SQL data

Tags: sql, vb.net

Yeah this is a pretty simple topic, but my form just isn't updating the row in the database:

Here's my code:

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If Request.QueryString("a") = "edit" Then
        Dim CategoryText As String = lstCategory.SelectedItem.Text

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=LogansArchive; Integrated Security=True;")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UpdateArticle", conn)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleID", Request.QueryString("i"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", CategoryText)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleTitle", txtNewTitle.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleContent", txtContent.Text)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    Else
        Dim CategoryText As String = lstCategory.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=LogansArchive; Integrated Security=True;")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("AddArticle", conn)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", CategoryText)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Now)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleTitle", txtNewTitle.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleContent", txtContent.Text)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the SP that the code refers to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateArticle]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ArticleID int,
    @Category varchar(20),
    @ArticleTitle varchar(100),
    @ArticleContent text
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE Articles
    SET
        Articles.Category = (SELECT CategoryID FROM Categories WHERE CategoryName = @Category),
        Articles.ArticleTitle = @ArticleTitle,
        Articles.ArticleContent = @ArticleContent
    WHERE Articles.ArticleID = @ArticleID
END
```

I've never used nested SELECTs in SQL before so I'm not sure if I did it right.
Aside from that, this is all stuff I've done before so I'm relatively sure that it's all correct.

Finally, there are no errors being reported when I debug, although the updates don't seem to be coming through from the text fields (txtContent.Text isn't changing to reflect the new value).

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

EDIT 1:
Thanks for the updates, I've looked at the `CInt(Request.Querystring("i"))` issue, and it doesn't solve the problem. I set a breakpoint on the start of the procedure and hovered over `txtContent.Text` to check the value of it's Text property in the intellisense. Bear in mind that the debugger is still on the first line of the procedure. The `txtContent.Text` property as shown by the debugger at this point contains none of the changes I made while testing.

Comment: Looks right to me.  Have you tested the procedure(s) from SSMS Query Analyzer?

Comment: I'm having trouble identifying a problem with the SQL so far.  My first instinct would be to set a breakpoint and verify that Request.QueryString("i") and CategoryText are getting values that correspond to something in the database, if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Are you saying that MyTextbox.Text is not showing the updated text input by the user?

Comment: I wonder if you could be passing the ArticleID as a string instead of an integer to the database?  Maybe setting the ArticleID like this in your code would work:           cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArticleID", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@ArticleID"].Value = i;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's taken 3 months, but I just found the answer.

The reason the debugger doesn't see any changes to my text fields is ... wait for it...

The fields are being populated from the database on page load.

I just had the same problem at work, and one of the other developers hit me with this. To fix the problem, place the code that populates the form into the following `IF` statement:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Populate the form out of the database here
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find refactoring code to remove duplication can be really helpful in debugging (and long-term maintenance).  Here is your code with the duplicated logic centralized a bit.  My guess is that your problem is that you are passing a `String` instead of an `Integer` to your SP for `ArticleID`.  You'll see that I did a `CInt(Request.QueryString("i"))` to ensure that you got an integer to work with instead of the string that `Request.QueryString("i")` returns.

You may also want to look at my TODO comment and put a breakpoint there and use the debugger to make sure that everything you expect made its way into the `cmd.Parameters` collection.

As far as the stored procedure goes, I don't see anything wrong with it.

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim categoryText As String = lstCategory.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim articleTitle = txtNewTitle.Text
    Dim articleContent = txtContent.Text

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=LogansArchive; Integrated Security=True;") 

    Dim cmd as SqlCommand

    If (Request.QueryString("a") = "edit") Then
        Dim articleId = CInt(Request.QueryString("i")) ' Convert provided Article ID to Int

        cmd = New SqlCommand("UpdateArticle", conn)    
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleID", articleId)
    Else
        cmd = New SqlCommand("AddArticle", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Now)    
    End If

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", categoryText)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleTitle", articleTitle)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleContent", articleContent)

    ' TODO: Put a breakpoint here and inspect cmd.Parameters to be sure they all contain what you expect them to contain.

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```